# Scaling Squared Strings

Tags: string, scala, count

Doing CodeWars challenges again.

Today I have a problem with this one:

"
You are given a string of n lines, each substring being n characters long. For example:

`s = "abcd\nefgh\nijkl\nmnop"`

We will study the "horizontal" and the "vertical" scaling of this square of strings.

A k-horizontal scaling of a string consists of replicating k times each character of the string (except '\n').

Example: 2-horizontal scaling of s: => `"aabbccdd\neeffgghh\niijjkkll\nmmnnoopp"`
A v-vertical scaling of a string consists of replicating v times each part of the squared string.

Example: 2-vertical scaling of s: => `"abcd\nabcd\nefgh\nefgh\nijkl\nijkl\nmnop\nmnop"`
Function scale(strng, k, v) will perform a k-horizontal scaling and a v-vertical scaling.

Example: `a = "abcd\nefgh\nijkl\nmnop"`
`scale(a, 2, 3)` --> "aabbccdd\naabbccdd\naabbccdd\neeffgghh\neeffgghh\neeffgghh\niijjkkll\niijjkkll\niijjkkll\nmmnnoopp\nmmnnoopp\nmmnnoopp"

"

The whole way of doing has to be entailed within a single function called "scale"

My problem is that with my experiments I've reached a certain point, in which I do not know how to move forward again. I have a list of lists of multiplied characters, but I haven't got a clue how to get the thing together again, so I can multiply it again using vertical scaling, according to the instruction

P.S. Just a clarification, I have not been working solely on the function itself, but within def main I have tried to reach the desired output, experimenting with a random string.

My plan was to develop the function itself only if I am happy with the output of the random string and if it fulfils the assumptions of the program.

If needed I will provide the tests, I did not do so in the first place because I consider my program too immature for such an action to be necessary.

All new ideas // break-ins to what I've already created are more than welcome, as I have to admit I've reached a dead end.

My current output:

`Vector(List(aa), List(bb), List(cc), List(dd), /, List(nn), List(ee), List(ff), List(gg), List(hh), /, List(nn), List(ii), List(jj), List(kk), List(ll), /, List(nn), List(mm), List(oo), List(pp))`

```
object Kata {

  def scale(xs: String, k: Int, n: Int): String = ???

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("abcd/nefgh/nijkl/nmop".map(x=>(if(x != '/'){x.toString()*2}else'/')).map(x=> if(x != '/')List(x)else "/"))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have confused the newline character, `\n`, with some imagined form of double-character delimiter, `/n`. Go back and re-read the challenge. You just need to multiply each character by the 1st `Int` parameter, and multiply each line by the 2nd `Int` parameter.

```
def scale(s :String, x :Int, y:Int) :String =
  s.split("\n")
   .map(_.map(_.toString*x).mkString("","","\n") * y)
   .mkString
```

testing:

```
val s = "abcd\nefgh\nijkl\nmnop"
scale(s, 3, 2)
//res0: String =
//"aaabbbcccddd
//aaabbbcccddd
//eeefffggghhh
//eeefffggghhh
//iiijjjkkklll
//iiijjjkkklll
//mmmnnnoooppp
//mmmnnnoooppp
//"
```